# Vertex shader (GLSL) strange behaviour; Does not draw

Tags: opengl, animation, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

I'm trying to implement skeletal animation using my vertex shader. I pass the indices and weights of my vertices as attributes, and upon drawing I pass the animation matrix for every bone as an array to my shader.

Now for some reason when I add the calculation to my shader my model disappears. Even if I do not use the result of the calculation ANYWHERE in my shader, it causes my shader to disappear. No errors are thrown.

I've done a lot of testing and found out that it only happens when I try to access animationMatrices[60]. As far as I've seen any index below 60 works. This is wierd however since I only have 53 bones in my model.

To illustrate, the following code doesn't draw anything:

```
#version 330


uniform vec3 light = vec3(10,2,8);

uniform mat4 modelmatrix;
uniform mat4[64] animationMatrices;

attribute vec3 a_tangent;
attribute vec4 a_boneIndices;
attribute vec4 a_boneWeights;

out vec3 lightVec;
out vec3 eyeVec;
out vec4 test;

void main()
{   
    vec4 newVert = (animationMatrices[60] * gl_Vertex) * a_boneWeights.x + gl_Vertex;
    vec4 vertPos = modelmatrix * gl_Vertex;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vertPos;
    eyeVec = normalize(-vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix*vertPos));

    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;

//some more stuff here but not important


}
```

If I comment out the newVert line, my model shows up.

So, if I remove or comment out this line the shader works fine (or change the index to something lower than 60):

```
vec4 newVert = (animationMatrices[60] * gl_Vertex) * a_boneWeights.x + gl_Vertex;
```

As soon as I re-introduce this line nothing shows up anymore even though newVert is not used anywhere in the shader.

Comment: Why are you adding `a_boneWeights.x + gl_Vertex` ?

Comment: as far as I know multiplication goes before addition, meaning I multiply the original vertex with the animation matrix first, then multiply the resulting vector with the weight and adding the resulting vector of that to the original vector. I doubt this is relevant though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `modelmatrix` is not an identity matrix, you are transforming your vertex incorrectly.

#### First from object-space to world-space:

```c
vec4 vertPos = modelmatrix * gl_Vertex;
```

#### And then from (what is ***supposed to be***) object-space to clip-space:

```c
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vertPos; // vertPos is in world-space!!!
```

You need to stop doing this, or isolate your View and Projection matrices.

#### Possible solutions:

```c
1. vertPos     = gl_Vertex;
2. gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix  * gl_Vertex;
3. gl_Position = projectionmatrix * viewmatrix * vertPos;
```

---

#### Considering a few lines below it, you compute something called `eyeVec`:

```c
eyeVec = normalize(-vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix*vertPos));
```

You probably should not be touching `vertPos` at all, the only way this shader will work properly is if `vertPos` = `gl_Vertex` (potential solution #1).

Comment: My shader works flawlessly without that one line in it however. My modelmatrix is just a matrix that transforms the vertices from local to world coords (to give them an offset/rotation/scale). This is not an answer to my question since that part of the shader works.

Comment: Exactly, without that line in it (that erroneously transforms the vertex position into world-space) your shader works flawlessly. Your `modelmatrix` is a matrix that transforms from object to world-space, and `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix` is a matrix that transforms from object-space to clip-space, ***not world-space to clip-space***. Your shader is completely wrong.

Comment: Your other problem is rather trivial: 64 * 4 * 4 = 1040. 1040 > 1024. You do not have enough uniform components to store 64 matrices in the vertex shader stage. If you need that many uniform components, you are going to need to use a Uniform Buffer Object. Otherwise you are restricted to 1024 components (and you will exceed this limitation ***before*** you actually use all 64 matrix indices, because you share uniform storage with other variables ***and*** things like constant literals in your shader).

Comment: That last comment was the answer to my question and solves my problems, thanks!

Comment: Good to know. The math was a little off though... You do require 1040 components in this shader, but that is because you have an array of 64 `mat4s` + 1 `mat4` for your model matrix. I would suggest you ditch your use of the fixed-function matrix stack while you are at it, if you have to adopt UBOs to solve your problem you should stop using features that are no longer available in core GL. Nip two problems in the bud at once. In fact, this shader probably will not compile in strict GLSL implementations because `#version 330` implies `#version 330 core`, instead of `#version 330 compatibility`